# Login PHP Session not working

Tags: php, session-cookies, login-script

I have a login form that checks the password and username entered and if correct it will give a message and makes login session true. But the session doesn't work. When it redirects you to dashboard you won't be able to visit it the value of session login is unknown. So when you enter userpass correct the session is not created for that moment but when you redirect it to another page your session is gone.

```html
<?PHP
 session_start();
   // Starting session
  
include 'config.php';
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
if (isset($_POST['user']) and isset($_POST['pass'])){




// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$result = $link->query("SELECT user FROM users2 WHERE user = '$user'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
  
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

         demo.initChartist();

         $.notify({
             icon: "pe-7s-bell",
             message: "Username of password was wrong. Please try again."

            },{
                type: "info",
                timer: 4000
            });

     });
 </script>';
  
} elseif ($result->num_rows == 1){
    $userpass = $link->query("SELECT pass FROM users2 WHERE user = '$user'");
$row = $userpass->fetch_assoc();
   $userpasss = $row["pass"];
    if ($pass == $userpasss){
       


 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

         demo.initChartist();

         $.notify({
             icon: "pe-7s-bell",
             message: "You are logged in successfully! Redirecting ..."

            },{
                type: "info",
                timer: 4000
            });

     });
 </script>';
 
 $_SESSION['login'] = "true";
$_SESSION['username'] = "$user";
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=3;URL='dashboard.php' />    ";
 echo $_SESSION["login"];
 echo $_SESSION["username"];

// Storing session data

    } else {
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

         demo.initChartist();

         $.notify({
             icon: "pe-7s-bell",
             message: "Username of password was wrong. Please try again."

            },{
                type: "info",
                timer: 4000
            });

     });
 </script>';
    }
}
} 
echo $_SESSION["login"];
?>
```

Where is the problem in the code?

Thank you

Warm regards

Comment: How are you checking that a user is logged in on your dashboard? Also, move your `session_start()` at the top of the page.

Comment: try to add session_start(); in all page that you want to be authenticated .

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I had  session_start(); when the operation was going to start. But now I've put the  session_start(); at top (Suggestion of @IcedAnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put  session_start(); at the Top of this page as you are accessing in global scope so you will get the session value.

- And i will suggest you to create different file for authentication purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. May I know the reason for creating a new page for authentication?
Most of the sites to it in the same page right? Or they use the 1st file to get info and then in 2nd file they authenticate and then they redirect user to 1st page and then to dashboard?
How does the process work?

Comment: i mean write code in different php file for authentication and then require those files here it not looks Good.. just a suggestion... And for your issue just related to session_start() .. or may be you are refreshing the page again that is causing something..

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I used 2 forms for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write all the page of the top `session_start()`

After successful login then redirect to dashboard.php need to add the first line

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['login]; ?>
```